# One column to two column list on python

Tags: python, list, calculated-columns

Good morning. I have list, that consist 2 probabilities:

```
[[0.84285885 0.15714115]
 [0.67180324 0.32819676]
 [0.95325917 0.04674083]
 ...
 [0.38825085 0.61174915]
 [0.45577896 0.54422104]
 [0.7975929  0.2024071 ]]
```

and another list, that consist ony one:

```
[[5.4913871e-02]
 [7.6471776e-02]
 [4.1644130e-04]
 ...
 [9.6865553e-01]
 [9.8211896e-01]
 [3.5812762e-01]]
```

How to transform this list to form of first list? Apply `1-x` to each element and get a list of the same shape. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the math lining up here.  Can you explain it better?

Comment: Are you sure that these are plain Python lists? You present them as if they were numpy arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have numpy array:

```py
a = np.array(
    [
        [5.4913871e-02],
        [7.6471776e-02],
        [4.1644130e-04],
        [9.6865553e-01],
        [9.8211896e-01],
        [3.5812762e-01],
    ]
)
```

Then:

```py
print(np.column_stack((a[:, 0], 1 - a[:, 0])))
```

Prints:

```py
[[5.49138710e-02 9.45086129e-01]
 [7.64717760e-02 9.23528224e-01]
 [4.16441300e-04 9.99583559e-01]
 [9.68655530e-01 3.13444700e-02]
 [9.82118960e-01 1.78810400e-02]
 [3.58127620e-01 6.41872380e-01]]
```